# How to get first error while using yup to validate object schema

Tags: reactjs, yup

I'm using Yup to validate nested data object against validation schema. I want to retrieve the path of the first validation error. I tried it with [validate()](https://github.com/jquense/yup#mixedvalidatevalue-any-options-object-promiseany-validationerror) of yup. It has the option `abortEarly` which defaults true. So in that case the first error should be returned.

However, I'm always getting the last error. I'm not sure what I'm missing out.

Below is the code that I've tried so far.

```
  const validationSchema = Yup.object().shape({
    basicDetails: Yup.object().shape({
      firstName: Yup.string().required("Required first name"),
      lastName: Yup.string().required("Required last name"),
      gender: Yup.string().required("Required gender"),
      phoneNumber: Yup.string().required("Required phone number"),
      emailId: Yup.string().required("Email id is required")
    }),
    educationDetails: Yup.object().shape({
      graduationDegree: Yup.string().required("Required graduation degree"),
      postGraduationDegree: Yup.string().required(
        "Required post graduation degree"
      ),
      registrationNumber: Yup.string().required("Required registration number"),
      workExperience: Yup.string().required("Required work experience")
    })
  });

  const dataObject = {
    basicDetails: {
      firstName: "Nik",
      lastName: "Test",
      gender: "male",
      phoneNumber: "9876543210",
      emailId: ""
    },
    educationDetails: {
      graduationDegree: "Degree 1",
      postGraduationDegree: "Postgraduation Degree 1",
      registrationNumber: "",
      workExperience: ""
    }
  };

  const validateSchema = async () => {
    const validationResult = await validationSchema
      .validate(dataObject)
      .catch((err) => {
        return err;
      });
    // this returns last error. however, as per the documentation, it should return the first error.
    console.log(validationResult.errors, validationResult.params);

    const validationResult1 = await validationSchema
      .validate(dataObject, { abortEarly: false })
      .catch((err) => {
        return err;
      });
    // this returns array of all errors in correct order.
    console.log(validationResult1.errors);
  };
```

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/distracted-agnesi-0piz7) is the code sandbox link for the minimal sample.

I also tried simple schema but got the same result.

Comment: I mean it's over-simplified, but if you switch the order in the yup schema to have `educationDetails` before `basicDetails`  (for validate nested) then the basicDetails error returns first.  It's not a proper solution to the overall issue, but at least your validation errors return the way you want.

Comment: @EspressoBeans I want the very first error to be returned irrespective of the placement of `basicDetails` or `educationDetails` object in data object. If i place `educationDetails` before `basicDetails` then there is fair chance that it will retrun error from `basicDetails`, however, in that case if `basicDetails` has multiple errors it will eventually return the last error and not the first.

Comment: Yes, that makes obvious sense.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think you'd need to validate with `abortEarly: false` and then use the first error. The reason is, `abortEarly` doesn't do what we think it would. It doesn't stop further validations once one error is found. As the validations are run in parallel per level of the schema.

Hence, I think this is how you'd need to do more or less:

```js
  const validateNestedSchema = async () => {
    const validationResult = await validationSchemaNested
      .validate(dataObjectNested, { abortEarly: false })
      .catch((err) => {
        return err;
      });
    console.log(validationResult.inner[0].path); // gives "basicDetails.emailId" 
  };
```

[the forked sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-rubin-k9wqk?file=/src/App.js), if needed

---

*FWIW, they seem to be discussing an option for validation chain in [this issue](https://github.com/jquense/yup/issues/851) but no conclusion/implementation yet it seems.*

Comment: Thanks @tanmay. It really solved my problem. I could not find this `validationResult.inner[0].path` in any documentation.

Answer (score 0):

This may be the solution for you.  The current structure of your schema is not nested, but an array of objects.  I think if you change the structure to the following, you'll get the results you're looking for:

```
const validationSchemaNested = Yup.object().shape({
  basicDetails: Yup.object().shape({
    firstName: Yup.string().required("Required first name"),
    lastName: Yup.string().required("Required last name"),
    gender: Yup.string().required("Required gender"),
    phoneNumber: Yup.string().required("Required phone number"),
    emailId: Yup.string().required("Email id is required"),
    educationDetails: Yup.object().shape({
      graduationDegree: Yup.string().required("Required graduation degree"),
      postGraduationDegree: Yup.string().required("Required post graduation degree"),
      registrationNumber: Yup.string().required("Required registration number"),
      workExperience: Yup.string().required("Required work experience")
    })
  }),

});


const dataObjectNested = {
  basicDetails: {
    firstName: "Nik",
    lastName: "Test",
    gender: "male",
    phoneNumber: "9876543210",
    emailId: "",
    educationDetails: {
      graduationDegree: "Degree 1",
      postGraduationDegree: "Postgraduation Degree 1",
      registrationNumber: "",
      workExperience: ""
    }
  }
};
```

I played around with it like this for a little bit and it seems to work the way you are wanting.

Comment: Thanks for taking time to answer. Unfortunately I can not change the schema of object. So your answer does not help in my case.